# How to pass a hash as optional argument to -M in command line

Tags: perl, hash, package, command-line-interface

I know that when we need to pass some arguments to the `use` keyword after a package name we can pass them in the command line after the `-M` parameter.

For example:

```
use feature 'say';
say 'hello!';
```

can be invoked from the command line with

```
>perl -Mfeature=say -e"say 'hello!'"
```

But what if the argument is a hash? Can I make a one-liner for the following example:

```
use constant {c1 => 'foo', c2 => 'bar'};
use feature 'say';
say c1, c2; #expected: foobar
```

This does not work:

```
>perl -Mfeature=say -Mconstant={c1,'foo',c2,'bar'} -e"say c1,c2"
Constant name '{c1' has invalid characters at -e line 0.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

Neither that:

```
>perl -Mfeature=say -Mconstant="c1,'foo',c2,'bar'" -e"say c1,c2"
'foo'c2'bar'c2
```

I know that I can add multiple `-Mconstant=foo` in the command line, but it is just an example; I have a package here that can take a hash at import and that I am trying to invoke from command-line.

Comment: `perl -wE 'use constant { FOO => 1, BAR => 2 }; say FOO, " ", BAR'` (Note that `-E` enables all features, so there's no need for `-Mfeature=say`)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: thanks for pointing the `-E` switch that I did not know. As I mentioned, `feature` is just an example, actually I was trying to import a custom module that takes a hash as parameter at import

Comment: well, just adding the `use` block in the `-e` argument is so simple that I did not think about it :o/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) use:

```
perl -Mfeature=say "-Mconstant {c1 => 'foo', c2 => 'bar'}" -e"say c1,c2"
```

Comment: Right. "`-Mmodule` executes use module ; before executing your program. You can use quotes to add extra code after the module name, e.g., `"-MMODULE qw(foo bar)"`." Thanks :o)